# Probability of an event

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Problem.** Suppose we have $n + 1$ random variable $\xi_0, \xi_1, \dots, \xi_n$ and they are independent and all standard normal distributed. Find probability that $\xi_0$ greater than $\max\{\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n\}$ at least in $\alpha > 1$ times.

**Solution.**

1. Let's find distribution of $\max\{\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n\}$. For me it's pretty obvious and intuitive that if $\xi_0$ has a distribution $F(x)$ and density $f(x)$ then $\max\{\xi_1, \dots, \xi_n\}$ distributed like $(F(x))^n$ and its density will be $f(x)n(F(x))^{n-1}$.
2. Let's integrate it over suitable domain.
   $$
   \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \int_{\alpha y}^{+\infty} f(x) n(F(y))^{n-1}f(y) dx dy = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} (1 - F(\alpha y)) n(F(y))^{n-1}f(y) dy
   $$

and I don't know how to deal with this integral because $F(x)$ has no good explicit form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this probability is also $$p_n(\alpha)=\int_\mathbb R\varphi(x)\Phi\left(\frac{x}\alpha\right)^n\mathrm dx,$$ and also $$p_n(\alpha)=\alpha\int_\mathbb R\varphi(\alpha x)\Phi\left(x\right)^n\mathrm dx,$$
thus, $p_n(1)=1/(n+1)$ and $p_n(\alpha)\to1/2^n$ when $\alpha\to+\infty$, but one can doubt that there is a general more explicit formula for $p_n(\alpha)$.